# Regex started by space and followed by numbers

Tags: regex

I'm trying to evaluate a string through regex with the following rules:
The string has exactly 5 characters, being the first n whitespaces and the last 5-n (at least 1) numbers.

`(\s*\d{1,5})` works, but also matches `"            12345"`, which is very outside of the rules.

Any idea?

Comment: P.S.: I'm a noob at regex business. Maybe a lookahead/lookbehind would help, but I still have no knowledge of it.

Comment: Side-note. Check out something like this. http://regexhero.net

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
^(?=.{5}$)\s*\d+$
```

The character limit is handled using a look ahead. The rest is straightforward.

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/67riCyFEh8)

Comment: `^(?=[\d\s]{5}$)\s*\d+$` would be even more precise.

Comment: @anubhava not really. the allowed characters are limited by the plain part. the look ahead is devoted just to length. I prefer separation like that. it also means that if you later change the allowed chars that you only have one part to maintain. If you include character info in the look ahead, you would have to change both parts.

Comment: +1 for short and sweet, it's true that the reverse `^(?=\s*\d+$).{5}$` works but the way you have it seems right as it fails faster. :)